# Can anyone tell me what this is

Tags: identification

I took this about a week ago, its always green and it very hearty[image]  It is in Kentucky, I noticed it when I bought the house, I have even tried to mow it down but its very tough

Comment: Can you give us a clue?  Like, where is it?

Comment: What plant/tree is the trunk behind it? Because it looks like this growth is coming off the base or roots of whatever it is...

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that looks like a young pampas grass. If it is, the edges of the long leaves are very sharp so be careful handling it as it can leave painful paper cuts. They can germinate from seeds blown on the wind from the fluffy plumes it produces in summer, when established, and can grow very big and wide.

Comment: The grass looks too coarse to be pampas grass (*Cortaderia* genus). I initially thought it might be Chinese Silver Grass (*Miscanthus sinensis*) or one of its cultivars because that grass is listed as invasive in Kentucky, but then I noticed that the characteristic white central vein was missing. My next thought is tufted hair grass (*Deschampsia*), which is at the southern limit of its range in Kentucky. About the only way to know for sure is to wait for flowers this summer.

Comment: It is some type of yucca, re the loose 'hairs' on the leaves visible in the photo.